# UIButton inside UIScrollView disables scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

After dragging a button to my scrollview, the window no longer scrolls! If I remove the button, scrolling now works.

Anyone run into this issue before?

```
//ScrollViewController.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;


//ScrollViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];
}
```

[image]

Comment: This [Answer] solve the problem under iOS 8[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25900859/3433059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it just worked after adding moving the code to viewDidLayoutSubiews.

Can someone explain WHY this works?

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad add:

```
self.scroller.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

Comment: Some explanation of why this is necessary might help.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing UIScrollView and adding code below into .m file, did solve my scrolling  freeze problem under iOS 8.

Code:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
    }
}
```

This solution was found in pasta12's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25900859/3433059