# Button on top of CollectionViewCell stops collectionView from scrolling

Tags: swift, scroll, uibutton, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with some cells in it.
On top of each cell i have a button, so when I press the button the view switches to another controller.

My problem now is, that when I touch the cell and try to scroll, it doesn't.
(Because of the button on top of it)

For the same issue in UIScrollView there's this method:

```
override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    // Makes the scrollView scrollable when there's a button on top.
    return true
}
```

I also tried this method instead:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Nothing")
}
```

And nothing happens.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Do you mean you have a button inside each cell? or do you mean that you have a button above each cell but that button is not children of cell?

Comment: I have a button inside each cell yes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad()` method of your `ViewController` set `collectionView.canCancelContentTouches = true`. I hope it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   self.scroller.isScrollEnabled = true
}
```

Based on the answer from Mark Kennedy, here: [UIButton inside UIScrollView disables scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047012/uibutton-inside-uiscrollview-disables-scrolling)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that the problem appears i a collectionView inside a collectionView cell.

Comment: I think i have to rewrite my question

Answer (score 0):

In Button tap method check if CollectionView is Scrolling or not. By Like this

```
if collectionView.isDragging || collectionView.isDecelerating {
 //`Don't go to Another View Controller`
}
```

Give a try.